# Delete up to first occurrence, edit that line and print the remaining lines unchanged

Tags: text-processing, sed, regular-expression

I have below text:

```
add gmt version date
comment - text1
text1 continue
comment - text2
text2 continue
comment - text 3
text3 continue
```

I want all text from first occurrence of "comment" to end of file.
I was using `sed 's/^.*Comment - //g'` I am getting only below text:

```
 text 3
 text3 continue
```

i.e. from last occurrence of "comment" to end of file.
but I need all text from first occurrence of "comment" to end of text i.e.

```
    text1
    text1 continue
    comment - text2
    text2 continue
    comment - text 3
    text3 continue
```

Comment: I have updated post. I want all text after "comment - " and rest of lines ( 5 lines in above example)

Comment: And with 's/^.*Comment - / /g' I am getting only 2 lines.

Comment: You _do_ realize that 4 lines in your input _don't match_ that regex so _it's impossible_ to get only 2 lines after running that command ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Done with a pipe, but it's not very nice

```
$ sed -n '/comment/,$ p' file | sed -r '0,/comment/ s/comment - (.*)/\1/'
text1
text1 continue
comment - text2
text2 continue
comment - text 3
text3 continue
```

Explanation

- `sed -n '/comment/,$ p' file` print lines from `comment` to the end
- `sed -r '0,/comment/ s/comment - (.*)/\1/'` find the first line with `comment` and edit it to remove `comment -`

Comment: Note that `-r` and the `0` address are GNU specific.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do this with `sed` is via command grouping:

```
{ sed '/PATTERN/!d;s///;q'; cat; } <infile
```

it `d`eletes all lines that don't match, on 1st match it `s`ubstitutes per your request and quits (autoprinting) then `cat` takes over and prints the remaining lines, if any.
Not to say you can't do it with `sed` alone:

```
sed '/PATTERN/,$!d         # delete all lines not in this range
//{                        # if the line matches
x;//!{                     # exchange and IF what was in hold space doesn't match
g;s///;b                   # get hold space content, replace, go to end of script
}
x                          # ELSE exchange back (do nothing)
}' <infile
```

---

I used `PATTERN` so as to keep it simple (replace it with `^.*comment -` or whatever the pattern is).

Comment: See also `sed '0,/PATTERN/{s///p;d}'` with GNU sed.